# Why should a program return a value?

Tags: c

I just wanna know what happens internally when we return a value. If we dont return a value what are the consequences?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  printf("Hello world");
  return 0; //what is use of this?
}
```

Comment: it's useful to know if something is success or failure and you can do that based on the exit status of a program.

Comment: when someone runs your program they can access the return code.  In linux you can do this: `echo $?` to see what the program that you just ran returned.

Comment: Nothing happens *internally*, because when you return from main() your program is finished. The return value of main() is useful *externally* when your app is finished.

Comment: Consider the shell snippet: `if ./a.out; then echo "my program was successful!"; else echo "my program failed"; fi`.  The value returned by your program (which I presume is compiled into `a.out`) determines which branch is taken.

Comment: *If we dont return a value what are the consequences?* You cannot avoid returning a value from `main`. This is the one function where, if you don't, the compiler will add it in for you.

Answer (score 1):

it can be evaluated by the system to determine if a program failed to run (and why it failed)

Comment: Concise, but the right answer. Could you maybe give examples of frequent error codes?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status

Answer (score 0):

I think perhaps you have two questions:

**Why does main() return `int` and not `void`?**

This question has [already been answered in many forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c). Basically: for the program that called it (a shell, perhaps, or your IDE), so that it can distinguish between success and various modes of failure.

**What happens if you forget to return a value from main()?**

In the first standardized version of C (C89) there was nothing special about main() in this respect. If you forgot to return a value, the behavior was undefined. In practice, most compilers will act as if you had put `return 0;`.

Since C99, if you do not return a value from main() explicitly, then main() is defined to return 0. main() is special in this way; other functions do not implicitly return anything.

As Weather Vane said in the comments, your program can't *not* return a value (on platforms where "return value" is a meaningful concept). On Linux, [execve()](https://linux.die.net/man/2/execve) and similar functions return an `int` that is the return value of the program. If a program were ill-behaved and did not intend to return a value, the return value would probably just be some arbitrary value (but it's possible that on another platform such a program would crash).

Answer (score -1):

Not every program or function returns a value. In c, we use return 0 in order to give back control to the operating system when the program is finished running and also to make sure that the program runs smoothly.
Hope that helps. Cheers